# I want rerender when props data change with react hooks but i got infinite rerender

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Sorry for my bad English.. But I need help you guys!
The problem is I wanna rerender when props change which is in EditField Components.

So I tried two ways,

first, I was trying to using useEffect parameter
In UseEffect Hooks I tried useEffect(() => {},[facils]... like this way
but when I tried this way, I got infinite rerender...

So I tried another ways, I passed GetDB function to EditField Components and when i edit my props data i tried call GetDBfunction.

But it didn't work what I expected...

could you give me any advices..?

```js
const GetDB = () => {
  const [facils, setFacils] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("facils")
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        const newFacils = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          ...doc.data(),
        }));
        // prevent firebase quote exceed
        console.log("!!!!FB warniing!!!!");
        setFacils(newFacils);
      });
  }, []);
  return facils;
};

const FacilityLists = () => {
  const facils = GetDB();
  const [id, setId] = useState([]);
  const [name, setName] = useState([]);
  const [showEdit, setShowEdit] = useState(false);

...
...
return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-evenly" }}>
        <div>Id</div>
        <div>시설이름</div>
      </div>
      <div>
        {facils.length > 0 ? (
          facils.map((item) => (
            <ul key={item.id} onClick={() => EditItem(item.id, item.name)}>
              {item.id} - {item.name}
            </ul>
          ))
        ) : (
          <p>there is no data</p>
        )}
      </div>
      <div>
        {showEdit ? (
          <EditField
            id={id}
            name={name}
            showSave={() => setShowEdit(false)}
            handleChange={handleChange}
            refreshData={() => GetDB}
          />
        ) : (
          <CreateField />
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot call a hook from a handler function. What you can do is implement and expose a fetcher from `GetDB` hook and call it.

Also make sure that when you create custom hooks, you prefix their name  with `use` since it will tell react to apply the [`rules of hooks`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) on it and warn you for incorrect usage

```
const useGetDB = () => {
  const [facils, setFacils] = useState([]);
  const fetchData = () => {
      firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("facils")
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        const newFacils = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          ...doc.data(),
        }));
        // prevent firebase quote exceed
        console.log("!!!!FB warniing!!!!");
        setFacils(newFacils);
      });
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  return { facils, fetchData};
};
```

Post that you can use it like below

```
const FacilityLists = () => {
  const {facils, fetchData} = useGetDB();
  const [id, setId] = useState([]);
  const [name, setName] = useState([]);
  const [showEdit, setShowEdit] = useState(false);

...
...
return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-evenly" }}>
        <div>Id</div>
        <div>시설이름</div>
      </div>
      <div>
        {facils.length > 0 ? (
          facils.map((item) => (
            <ul key={item.id} onClick={() => EditItem(item.id, item.name)}>
              {item.id} - {item.name}
            </ul>
          ))
        ) : (
          <p>there is no data</p>
        )}
      </div>
      <div>
        {showEdit ? (
          <EditField
            id={id}
            name={name}
            showSave={() => setShowEdit(false)}
            handleChange={handleChange}
            refreshData={() => fetchData()}
          />
        ) : (
          <CreateField />
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
I tried your ways, but I can't use fetchData() in refreshData..
I got messages not defined variable.
and facils.map is not working, I couldn't see any ul even i got data in db

Comment: Where do you see the error? have you destructured and returns the value correctly from useGetData. Also why can't you use fetchData in refreshData?

Comment: in refreshData={() => fetchData()}...
yes i destructured and returns value correctly, but I can't use fetchData variables..
I got same situations If i declared useGetData in Facility Component and outside Facility Component.

Comment: Oopss.. Sorry, I didn't destructure useGetDB hooks, I'll try agian!

Answer (score 1):

Rename your `GetDB` to `useFacils`. A hook's name starts with `use` word, and hooks (useEffect) are only called within function components or other hooks. Not sure why you didn't got a lint error when you created the GetDb hook.

from the docs:

> Its name should always start with use so that you can tell at a glance
>   that the rules of Hooks apply to it.

and also:

> Do I have to name my custom Hooks starting with “use”? Please do. This
>   convention is very important. Without it, we wouldn’t be able to
>   automatically check for violations of rules of Hooks because we
>   couldn’t tell if a certain function contains calls to Hooks inside of
>   it.

This was just an advice regarding your hooks name, as Shubham pointed in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61955885/7104283), to make the refresh work, you should also make your custom hook return the fetch/refresh function.

```
const useDbFacils = () => {
  const [facils, setFacils] = useState([]);

  const fetchFacils = React.useCallback(() => {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("facils")
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        const newFacils = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          ...doc.data(),
        }));
        setFacils(newFacils);
      });
  }, [setFacils]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchFacils();
  }, [fetchFacils]); // only you knows if this dependency is needed
  return [facils, fetchFacils];
};
```

In your component:

```
function FacilsList() {
  const [facils, fetchFacils] = useDbFacils();

  // later
  {facils.length > 0 ? facils.map...
  // and
  <EditField
    id={id}
    name={name}
    showSave={() => setShowEdit(false)}
    handleChange={handleChange}
    refreshData={fetchFacils}
  />
}
```

Comment: Using `use` prefix is not a compulsion for compilation. It just helps react add validation and provide warning for incorrect usage: Check this codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-bush-qpldx. Without the prefix react won't be able to validate the rules of hooks against it but it will still work if you used it correctly: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#extracting-a-custom-hook

Comment: Thanks for helpful advice.. I didn't know that!

Comment: I have one more questions, why I can't use useEffect with parameter directly..? why i'm getting infinite rerender...? why I should use hooks with returning function.
I can't clearly understand..

Comment: here you go, this is the best i ve read so far : https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/

Comment: But to answer your question, of course you can do it. You just posted a code snippet where you had a custom hook fetching facils for you, but you can just copy its content to your component (will become huge)

Comment: first, I'll read your recommended articles and tried to understand.. Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

You need to preset the custom hook with "use", or react will not recognize it as a hook and will create a new hook on every render because it will not be memorized.

Change it to useDB and it should work.

Comment: I think just not a "use" problem

Comment: @youngbanas you can see in the other answer, that was actually the problem to not use use.